# uitabbar loads after uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios

In a UITabBar based application, UIImagePickerController is opened ,after dismissing it UIViewController loads earlier than UITabBar and as a result whole content of UIViewController is not being shown?

Comment: Are you asking what will happen? Or how to make them load in a certain order? Or what will happen if they are loaded in this order? Please clarify.

Comment: Can you add more details about your problem. This is not enough for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess after dismissing controller method for navigation would be an issue.

Check if you use below method:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Then it will navigate flow to root controller.

So replace this method with

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Above method pop back to previous controller.

Comment: After dismissing UIImagePickerController , UIViewController loads earlier , then tabbar gets loaded . Due to this, the bottom content of UIViewController is not being shown.So, we want that tabbar loads earlier and then uiviewcontroller gets load so that the whole content is shown.